# Get the name of the category corresponding to the maximum value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, max

I have a pandas dataframe with football team, football players and the number of minutes played during the season.

| Team | Player | Minutes played |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 |
| 1 | b | 10 |
| 1 | c | 0 |
| 2 | a | 28 |
| 2 | b | 50 |
| 2 | e | 7 |
| 3 | c | 200 |
| 3 | p | 10 |

By doing :

```
df['count_max'] = df.groupby(['Team'])['Minutes played'].transform(max)
df
```

I get a new column with the maximum number of minutes played for each team

| Team | Player | Minutes played | Count_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | b | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | c | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | a | 28 | 50 |
| 2 | b | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | e | 7 | 50 |
| 3 | c | 200 | 200 |
| 3 | p | 10 | 200 |

But instead of this information, I would like to display the letter corresponding to the player (b for 1, b for 2 and c for 3).
Do you know how can I update my code to do so ?

My expected output is :

| Team | Player | Minutes played | Count_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 | b |
| 1 | b | 10 | b |
| 1 | c | 0 | b |
| 2 | a | 28 | b |
| 2 | b | 50 | b |
| 2 | e | 7 | b |
| 3 | c | 200 | c |
| 3 | p | 10 | c |

Comment: Where do you want to put the letter, what is the expected outptu?

Comment: I've updated my post to add the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmax` in `transform` and map the index to `Player` column.

```py
df['count_max'] = df.groupby('Team')['Minutes played'].transform('idxmax').map(df['Player'])
```

```
print(df)

   Team Player  Minutes played count_max
0     1      a               2         b
1     1      b              10         b
2     1      c               0         b
3     2      a              28         b
4     2      b              50         b
5     2      e               7         b
6     3      c             200         c
7     3      p              10         c
```

Comment: That worked for me thanks you